# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct pt_regs’

Tags: android, hook, ptrace

I am trying to use ptrace on Android to hook.
when I compile code below(with ndk or command "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc hook1.c -o hook1"), I got the error message. I try to solve it, but I can not succeed. 
Could anyone help me? T_T

hook1.c(code)

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

long getSysCallNo(int pid, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    long scno = 0;
    scno = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, (void *)(regs->ARM_pc - 4), NULL);
    if(scno == 0)
        return 0;

    if (scno == 0xef000000) {
        scno = regs->ARM_r7;
    } else {
        if ((scno & 0x0ff00000) != 0x0f900000) {
            return -1;
        }
        scno &= 0x000fffff;
    }
    return scno;    
}

void hookSysCallBefore(pid_t pid)
{
    struct pt_regs regs;
    int sysCallNo = 0;

    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);    
    sysCallNo = getSysCallNo(pid, &regs);
    printf("Before SysCallNo = %d\n",sysCallNo);

    if(sysCallNo == __NR_write)
    {
        printf("__NR_write: %ld %p %ld\n",regs.ARM_r0,(void*)regs.ARM_r1,regs.ARM_r2);
    }
}

void hookSysCallAfter(pid_t pid)
{
    struct pt_regs regs;
    int sysCallNo = 0;

    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);  
    sysCallNo = getSysCallNo(pid, &regs);

    printf("After SysCallNo = %d\n",sysCallNo);

    if(sysCallNo == __NR_write)
    {
        printf("__NR_write return: %ld\n",regs.ARM_r0);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <pid to be traced>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(0 != ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL))
    {
        printf("Trace process failed:%d.\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL);

    while(1)
    {
        wait(&status);
        hookSysCallBefore(pid);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL);

        wait(&status);
        hookSysCallAfter(pid);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

compile info

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I missed an file named Application.mk.
When I added the file to Eclipse, I could compile successfully.